# How to move PHP script from svn repository to document root

Tags: linux, svn, redhat, post-commit

I am a newbie on Subversion using Redhat 6.

I have difficulties on applying post commit from subversion.
I want to update my php scripts on document root automatically if i have commit it from svn clients.

Comment: If you want people to spend time writing up a solution for you, you need to spend the time to write up your problem in the first place!  I can't read your mind!

Comment: You said "I have difficulties applying post commit from subversion". What did you do?  What happened? What did you see?  What are the error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Post-commit hook (Check Manual: SVN Book) and `svn export` (RTM `svn help export`)